# Magento 2.2 sendmail return-path

Tags: magento2, email, send-mail

I've installed Magento 2.2 in local computer on Windows and on remote server on Centos/Plesk.

In both installation return-path is set to NO.

On windows sendmail set return-path as sender email.

On Centos/Plesk sendmail set return-path as domainuser@domain.com.

Did I miss some configuratione on remote installation?

Comment: what do you want the return path to be like?

Comment: i would like to be set as sender email but i figured it out that it doesn't work whit sendmail. in windows i'm using smtp.

Comment: you can set the return path to specific or you can use a magento plugin for  smtp support